# Запуск видео с hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, хотел сделать так, чтоб при событии onMouseOut видео отмоталось назад. Но после того как видео отмоталось запуск не происходит

```
<video id="video" muted preload class="pokyHover" src="./Vehicle Exploded View Animation_Trim.mp4"> 
</video>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.pokyHover').hover(
    () => {
        video.currentTime = 0;
        video.play()
    }, //onMouseEnter
    () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            video.currentTime += -.1;
        }, 30);
        video.pause()
    } //onMouseOut
    );
   </script>
```

Comment: onmouseover а не hover

Comment: Даже если убрать video.pause() ничего не изменится

Comment: Leonid, не не помогло

Comment: `setInterval` то надо когда-то остановить. Ну и видео запустить когда-то. Мне кажется, у вас проблема с целью - представьте по шагам, что вы хотите.

Comment: Нужно, чтоб при наведении на видео оно запускалось, а при onMouseOut отмоталось в начало, при этом, после перемотки видео при наведении должно запускаться

Comment: video.onmouseout.currentTime = 0; вот так вроде

Comment: video.onmouseover.play(); - так старт видео

Comment: @MaximLensky мне нужно именно, чтоб оно отмоталось, поэтому там и setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в нужном месте останавливать `setInterval`.

Посмотрите пример.

```js
let intervalId;
$('.pokyHover').hover(
  () => {
    //Очищаем интервал перемотки назад
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    video.play();
  }, //onMouseEnter
  () => {
    //Очищаем интервал перемотки назад, на случай, если onMouseEnter не сработал
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    video.pause()
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      video.currentTime += -.1;
      if (video.currentTime <= 0) {
        //Очищаем интервал перемотки назад когда дошли до начала видео
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, 30);
  } //onMouseOut
);
```

```css
video {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" muted preload class="pokyHover" src="https://v.mover.uz/1Jfy4tcm_h.mp4"> 
</video>
```